# How to remove CRLF characters from a flat file generated by BizTalk

Tags: flatfile

Can you please tell me how to remove CRLF characters from a flat file which has been generated by BizTalk?

Appreciate your quick response to this question, as we are in the middle of a critical delivery.

Thanks and Regards
Madhu

Answer (score 0):

Using any editor or word processor, search and replace CR and LF with nothing.
The example below uses free Notepad++, which uses C-style `\r` and `\n` for Carrige return and Newline, respectively. LibreOffice *Writer*, MS *Word* and other editors/processors use different characters for char(0x0D) and char(0x0A).

[image: Search & Replace CRLF]

Comment: Thanks very much. But I want to know how to avoid CRLF getting generated at the first place. I have seen another post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338025/biztalk-flat-file-produces-crlf-even-when-empty-data, which says not to map anything to the destination to avoid CRLF. We will check regarding this on Feb 4, but appreciate any other inputs. Thanks.

Comment: @MadhuManchi, then change the question you asked, "How to remove CRLF", to reflect that.